# Differences in Xpath evalution between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, xpath

**Goal**: Trying to select a cell from the nth table by supplying a table index, column header, and row number.  The xpath I have works in Firefox, but not Chrome.

The same xpath is working within Firefox, but failing to evaluation in Chrome.

The xpath is attempting to select a cell in a table using the column header.

**Work in Firefox, but not Chrome**

```
(//table)[count((//table)[5]/descendant::th)]
```

Firefox, returns the table according to the number of columns in table 5, but Chrome returns nothing.

```
((//table)[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td)[count((//table)[2]/descendant::th[.='TextField']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]
```

Firefox returns the cell in the first row in the 'TextField' column, Chrome returns nothing.

The html I am working with is a bit of a div soup as you can see below. Try running the snippet in Chrome vs Firefox, the results will be different (they  can be found if you run the snippet and scroll all the way down).

```js
// Print title
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<h2>Table Query Results<\/h2>');
// Evaluate the xpath
var resultTable = document.evaluate("(//table)[count((//table)[2]/descendant::th)-3]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var resultTableVal = null;
// If the xpath returned a result, grab the first result
if (resultTable != null) resultTableVal = resultTable.iterateNext();
// If both the xpath result and first result have values
if (resultTable != null && resultTableVal != null) {
  // Create a pre tag
  var preTable = document.createElement('pre');
  // While there are results
  while (resultTableVal) {
    // Add them to pre
    preTable.textContent += 'Found ' + resultTableVal.outerHTML + '\n';
    resultTableVal = resultTable.iterateNext();
  }
  document.body.appendChild(preTable);
}
else {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<p>No node found.<\/p>');
}

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<h2>Cell Query Results<\/h2>');
var resultCell = document.evaluate("((//table)[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td)[count((//table)[2]/descendant::th[.='TextField']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var resultCellVal = null;
if (resultCell != null) resultCellVal = resultCell.iterateNext();
if (resultCell != null && resultCellVal != null) {
  var preCell = document.createElement('pre');
  while (resultCellVal) {
    preCell.textContent += 'Found ' + resultCellVal.outerHTML + '\n';
    resultCellVal = resultCell.iterateNext();
  }
  document.body.appendChild(preCell);
}
else {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<p>No node found.<\/p>');
}
```

```css
table { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h3>Grids</h3>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <span>EditableGrid</span><em>*</em>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <p></p>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <div>
                          <table>
                            <colgroup>
                              <col>
                              <col>
                              <col>
                              <col>
                              <col>
                              <col>
                              <col>
                            </colgroup>
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>
                                  <div>
                                    <h2>TextField</h2><a><i></i></a>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                  <div>
                                    <h2>ParagraphField</h2><a><i></i></a>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                  <div>
                                    <h2>EncryptedTextField</h2><a><i></i</a>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                  <div>
                                    <h2>IntegerField</h2><a><i></i></a>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                  <div>
                                    <h2>DecimalField</h2><a><i></i></a>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                  <div>
                                    <h2>DateField</h2><a><i></i></a>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  <div>
                                    <div>
                                      <div>
                                        <span><em>*</em>
                                        <label>Label</label></span>
                                        <div>
                                          <div>
                                            Text Input
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                          <p></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div></div>
                                        <div></div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  <div>
                                    <div>
                                      <div>
                                        <span><em>*</em>
                                        <label>Label</label></span>
                                        <div>
                                          <div>
                                            Paragraph input
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                          <p></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div></div>
                                        <div></div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  <div>
                                    <div>
                                      <div>
                                        <span><em>*</em>
                                        <label>Label</label></span>
                                        <div>
                                          <div>
                                            Encrypted Text input
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                          <p></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div></div>
                                        <div></div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  <div>
                                    <div>
                                      <div>
                                        <span><em>*</em>
                                        <label>Label</label></span>
                                        <div>
                                          <div>
                                            Integer Input
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                          <p></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div></div>
                                        <div></div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  <div>
                                    <div>
                                      <div>
                                        <span><em>*</em>
                                        <label>Label</label></span>
                                        <div>
                                          <div>
                                            Decimal input
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                          <p></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div></div>
                                        <div></div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  <div>
                                    <div>
                                      <div>
                                        <span><em>*</em>
                                        <label>Label</label></span>
                                        <div>
                                          <div>
                                            <div>
                                              Date input
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                          <p></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div></div>
                                        <div></div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <span>ReadOnlyGrid</span><em>*</em>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <p></p>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <div>
                          <table>
                            <colgroup>
                              <col>
                              <col>
                              <col>
                              <col>
                              <col>
                              <col>
                            </colgroup>
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>
                                  <div>
                                    <h2>TextField</h2><a><i></i></a>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                  <div>
                                    <h2>ParagraphField</h2><a><i></i></a>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                  <div>
                                    <h2>EncryptedTextField</h2><a><i></i>/a>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                  <div>
                                    <h2>IntegerField</h2><a><i></i></a>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                  <div>
                                    <h2>DecimalField</h2><a><i></i></a>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                  <div>
                                    <h2>DateField</h2><a><i></i></a>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot></tfoot>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Column1</td>
                                <td>Column2</td>
                                <td>Column3</td>
                                <td>Column4</td>
                                <td>Column5</td>
                                <td>Column6</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      <span>EditableGrid</span><em>*</em>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <table>
                          <colgroup>
                            <col>
                            <col>
                            <col>
                            <col>
                          </colgroup>
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <div>
                                  <h2>PickerField1</h2><a><i></i></a>
                                </div>
                              </th>
                              <th>
                                <div>
                                  <h2>PickerField2</h2><a><i></i></a>
                                </div>
                              </th>
                              <th>
                                <div>
                                  <h2>PickerField3</h2><a><i></i></a>
                                </div>
                              </th>
                              <th>
                                <div>
                                  <h2>PickerField4</h2><a><i></i></a>
                                </div>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tfoot></tfoot>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>Userpick data</td>
                              <td>Grouppicker data</td>
                              <td>User group picker data</td>
                              <td>Document picker</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>Folder Picker</td>
                              <td>Document folder picker</td>
                              <td>Custom picker</td>
                              <td><span>*</span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to reproduce the problem with `(//table)[count((//table)[5]/descendant::th)]`:

```js
var result = document.evaluate('(//table)[count((//table)[5]/descendant::th)]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
if (result != null) {
  var pre = document.createElement('pre');
  pre.textContent = 'Found ' + result.outerHTML;
  document.body.appendChild(pre);
}
else {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<p>No node found.<\/p>');
}
```

```css
table { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<table id="t1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>table 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="t2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>table 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="t3">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>table 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="t4">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>table 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="t5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>table 5 header </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>table 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I get the same result with Firefox, Edge and Chrome, the first table is selected as the fifth one has one `th` element. Consider to edit your question and insert code snippets allowing us the reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay, it took me a while (first time asking a question), but I've added a snippet following your template and if you run it on chrome and firefox you will see the results I was referring to.

Comment: Fine, as far as I have checked the Chrome result with `var resultTable = document.evaluate("(//table)[count((//table)[2]/descendant::th)-3]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
` is a clear bug so you might want to report that. The second looks also like a bug as both Edge and Firefox find a cell, although I haven't checked all the details. Again something to report to Google.

Comment: I did report through the chrome app, just was wondering if there was another work around that would work with all of the browsers.

Comment: @MichaelChirlin - I cannot find your issue (I might not have the necessary permission) - can you file it at https://crbug.com if you cannot find a similar existung one? This way, it will be a public issue and others could follow it for progress. Thank you!

Comment: @PhistucK, I originally submitted through the Chrome browser 'Report and Issue'.  But now I've submitted it as a [Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=625710#).